# JavascriptInterface in Android's WebView: multiple calls to JS cause deadlock

Tags: javascript, android, webview

This is the entire Java code I've used. I will explain in more detail below...

```
public class Test7 extends Activity {
    //debug
    private final static String TAG = "JSInterface";

    private WebView wv;

    private class JSInterface {
        private WebView wv;

        // Variables to manage interfacing with JS
        private String returnValue;
        private boolean canReadReturnValue;
        private Lock lockOnJS;
        private Condition condVarOnJS;

        public JSInterface (WebView wv) {
            this.wv = wv;       
            this.canReadReturnValue = false;
            this.lockOnJS = new ReentrantLock();
            this.condVarOnJS = lockOnJS.newCondition();
        }

        public void setReturnValue(String ret) {
            lockOnJS.lock();
            returnValue = ret;
            canReadReturnValue = true;
            condVarOnJS.signal();
            lockOnJS.unlock();
            Log.d(TAG, "returnValue = " + returnValue);
        }

        public String getReturnValue() {
            Log.d(TAG, "enter in getReturnValue");
            lockOnJS.lock();
            while (!canReadReturnValue) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get wait...");
                    condVarOnJS.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            lockOnJS.unlock();
            Log.d(TAG, "returnValue: " + returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        }

        public String getNewString() {
            wv.loadUrl("javascript:JSInterface.setReturnValue(createNewString())");         
            return getReturnValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(wv), "JSInterface");
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/prova7.html");
    }

    public void button1(View v) {
        wv.loadUrl("javascript:func('1')");
    }
}
```

And it seems work fine.

You can see that I've got a button (that we can call **button1**), and clicking on it, it tries to execute a JS method, called **func()**.

```
public void button1(View v) {
    wv.loadUrl("javascript:func('1')");
}
```

Inside this JS method, I have to call another Java method. This is the code:

```
function func(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = JSInterface.getNewString();
}
```

I need to return the result of JSInterface.getNewString() to the innerHTML variable.

The code of **JSInterface.getNewString()** is this:

```
public String getNewString() {
    wv.loadUrl("javascript:JSInterface.setReturnValue(createNewString())");         
    return getReturnValue();
}
```

You can see that I use the method `setReturnValue` and `getReturnValue` to return the value returned by another JS method. This is the code:

```
function createNewString() {
    return "my New String";
}
```

The problem is that when I try to set the returnValue, the function createNewString is never executed! If I add a console.log() line, my logCat display nothing!

I cannot understand why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the javascript and your JSInterface methods called from javascript **are running on the single thread in Android `WebView`**. So while you are waiting in `condVarOnJS.await()` no javascript can be executed, just because it is executed on the same thread.

Moreover, all the webview instances in your application share the same javascript thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer I found the same problem. You can use setTimeout like this:

```
function func(id) {
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = JSInterface.getNewString();
        }, 
        500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the functionality what you intend in that code,for me createNewString() is called,

I will show up the code i used,

In java
,

```
   public String  videoPlay(){
        System.out.println("videoPlay");
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.demo.setReturnValue(createNewString())");
        return getReturnValue();}

public void setReturnValue(String test){
        rotValue=test;
        System.out.println(test);

    }
    public String getReturnValue(){
        System.out.println("get"+rotValue);
        return rotValue;
    }
```

in HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <script>
function inform(){
    alert('et');

   document.getElementById('myText').value=window.demo.videoPlay();
   alert('et');
 }
function createNewString() {
    return "my New String";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<form>
<input type='text' id='myText' />
<input type="button" name="test" value="Click me" onclick="inform()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The function getter and setter called and values also set, but i have the output log as..

```
11-08 19:18:17.155: INFO/System.out(847): videoPlay
11-08 19:18:17.165: INFO/System.out(847): getnull
11-08 19:18:17.875: INFO/System.out(847): my New String
```

videoPlay called from JS and createnewString() also called from java to JS , but it returns the value before it set , because i don`t what is the purpose to use lock , even i tried using lock as you did for that it will print

```
 11-08 19:18:17.155: INFO/System.out(847): videoPlay
    11-08 19:18:17.165: INFO/System.out(847): getnull
```

using lock also the function callback works in wrong manner, you need work on locks.